# request npm module not working after recent update

Tags: node.js, npm, request, httpclient

Code was working absolutely fine before 20 days, and now I am trying to run the same code, but it doesn't work anymore ( doesn't even shows any error).

```
     var request = require("request");
     var dataToSend = {
              key: "value",
              key1: "value1"
            };

    request.post({
            url: 'http://localhost:9092/services/reports/generateReport',
            form: dataToSend
        }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', err);
            }
        })
          .on('response', function (response) {
            console.log('success log'); 
            res.download('public/uploads/report.pdf');
        })
          .on('error', function (response) {
            console.log('Error downloading report file');
        })
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public/uploads/report.pdf'));
```

**output is always "success log" . even If I write some random URL then also it shows "success log"**

Web service is working fine, I have verified it with an external REST client.

Problem here is:

1) It doesn't care what URL I write, will go into 'response' part without giving any 'error'.

2) how to debug it? doesn't show any error

Note: recently there was an update in request module, could that be a problem ?

I was just about to push this code in Production and got error while running npm install. please help me, I don't want to move to another rest HTTP-client.

```
node v4.4.5
npm v3.10.8
request v2.75.0
```

Comment: for 404 error it will go to the response event only, try xy23234z.com and see if it logs the error.

Comment: that's the problem, it doesn't show any error

Comment: Do a `console.log(response);` in you success handler and see what it gives you.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the event handlers when passing a callback. The code can be refactored to:

```
request.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:9092/services/reports/generateReport',
    form: dataToSend
}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('upload failed:', err);

        return res.status(500); 
    }

    //
    // TODO: Check if the HTTP status code fits your expectations:
    //
    // if (httpResponse.status !== 201) {
    //     return res.status(500);
    // }
    //

    res.download('public/uploads/report.pdf');
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried your code.

Problem: It simply ignores what URL I am typing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some other request.post() styles. This may solve your problem with reading the URL.

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
// or 
request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'})
// or 
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })
```

You get your request to the server with "response.request". You can see the receiving host in there.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all those options. Let me tell you, it just doesn't stop for POST request, it won't even let GET request pass through. as if nothing is working with request module. it is not just me, some other people are also having same issue. check this :  https://gitter.im/request/request

Comment: notion's answer above works for me (6.8.0). Have you tried updating your node version to 4.6.0 (LTS) or 6.8.0 (latest)?

Comment: @DhruvilThaker If you see that others have this problem as well and it seems to be a bug in  a module, why do you ask a question here? Why don't you post an issue there: https://github.com/request/request/issues

If you are struggling with request because it has a bug, why don't you switch to superagent? It has almost the same interface.

Comment: @DanielKhan I didn't knew that before asking the question here.and if I already know that, why would I even use my Reputation points for bounty?

Answer (score 0):

If you think it got broke because of recent `request` module update then you can just roll back to old release version of `request` module and everything should be fine and start working as was before.

e.g

Your package is host on github here:

`https://github.com/request/request`

And specific version is:

`v2.75.0`

then you can specify specific version like this in your `package.json` (If you are using package.json) or other place where you mentioned your `request` module

```
https://github.com/request/request#v2.75.0
```

Hope, this helps you